# Can I set specific lines to be included by default in new files?

Tags: command-line, text-editor

Can I save specific lines in a text file which can be shown always by default whenever I make another text file again in the future?

As an example, when I make a new text file in Ubuntu it's going to be blank. What I need is when I make a new text file in Ubuntu I want to see some specific lines by default such as `#include <stdio.h> and return 0 ;`

Comment: so i need to make a new template everytime ???? with new #include and return 0 ?? @Nmath

Comment: oh ok ok thanks alot for your help !! have a nice day <3 .

Answer (score 0):

**Make a template.**

A template is just a file that you've created in advance that you can use as a base for new documents.

- Open your text editor of choice and add the information that you want to appear in all new documents.
- Save this file somewhere you will remember.

  As an example, we'll name the file `shoppinglist.txt` and save this file to `~/Templates/`
- (Optional) You can make the file read-only so that you don't accidentally overwrite your template:

  ```
  chmod 444 ~/Templates/shoppinglist.txt
  ```
- Whenever you want to make a document with this template, just open the file at `~/Templates/shoppinglist.txt`.  Use *"Save As..."* so that you don't overwrite your template.  If you made the file read-only in the previous step, this will be an extra fail safe that you won't overwrite this file.

Answer (score 0):

#### Command line

- Create a function like:

  ```
  newfile () {

  if [ -f "$1" ]; then
      echo "File $1 already exists." # Check if the file exists and if so, print a message and don't create the file.
  else    
      pre_text='#include <stdio.h> and return 0 ;' # This line will be prepended to the new file.
      echo "$pre_text" > "$1"
  fi

  }
  ```
- Then, add it to your `~/.bashrc` file and activate it for the first time by either closing your terminal window and opening a new one or by running `source ~/.bashrc`.
- Then, from now on, create new files of interest like so:

  ```
  newfile file.txt
  ```

#### GUI(*nautilus right click*)

- Create a new template file under `~/Templates` like so:

  ```
  echo "#include <stdio.h> and return 0 ;" > ~/Templates/'C File.c'
  ```
- Select your new template "**C File**" under "**New Document**" from the **right click** anywhere in your Desktop Environment.